# In GraphQL, how do I implement optional queries?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

EDIT: Since it doesn't seem to be clear, I am specifically asking about the DB requests I should be making inside the resolve function for a query on the backend.

I am implementing GraphQL queries, and I am having trouble understanding exactly how many calls I should make in a given query. For example, here's a data structure with users and clubs that the user can join:

```
User {
  UserID
  Clubs
  OtherStuff
}

Club{
  ClubID
  ClubName
}
```

I have the following calls I can make to my DB:

- Get all UserIDs
- Get info for UserID
- Get all ClubIDs for a user
- Get info for ClubID

The thing I don't understand is whether I should be making all of these calls every time Users is queried. If someone is only querying UserIDs, it seems like a huge waste to retrieve everything else. Should Clubs for User be a totally separate GraphQL query, should Clubs only return ClubIDs, or is there a way to efficiently allow full Club info to be available in the Clubs field?

EDIT 2:
Ok so here's my code. I've commented the part where I'm not sure what to do.

```
const QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    User: userQueryField,
    Club: clubQueryField
  }
});

const clubQueryField = {
  type: new GraphQLList(ClubType),
  args: {
    UserID: {
      description: 'Returns all clubs the user is a part of',
      type: GraphQLID
    }
  },
  resolve(root, {UserID}) {
    //.....
  }
};


const userQueryField = {
  type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
  args: {
    UserID: {
      description: 'If omitted, returns a list of all users. \
      Otherwise, returns the user with the provided ID',
      type: GraphQLID
    }
  },
  resolve(root, {UserID}) {
    if(UserID){
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getUserInfo(UserID, function(response){

          //HERE: I have tried different things, like clubQueryField(UserID) and clubQueryField.resolve, but with no luck
          UserID.Clubs = clubQueryField
          resolve([response]);
        });
      });
    }
  }
};
```

EDIT 3: UserType definition.

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: () => ({
    UserID: {
      type: GraphQLID
    },
    Clubs: {
      type: new GraphQLList(ClubType)
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: This is all done in the resolver, interfacewise, you pass the information required for the resolver to fetch the information. Yes, the resolver should make all these calls. of course, you can use caching to speed it up. From your question I can tell you are confusing GraphQL Query with backend query.

Comment: I don't think I am confusing them, but maybe my wording isn't clear. What makes you think I am confusing them?

Comment: the wording. ;-)

Comment: heh yea I got that, I mean what wording?

Comment: @OlivierRefalo Check the edit

Comment: Where is USERTYPE defined? You should sent the data to USERTYPE and then parse it there. I don't understand why you wrote resolver in resolver. You mentioned  `type: new GraphQLList(UserType)`, however never defined it. In the USERTYPE schema you should send back an array of user ids.

Comment: I just edited in my UserType definition. I'm confused by the idea of including the resolver in the fields, since most of the fields are set by the same call - do I just add a resolver to the fields where an additional call would be required? What would that look like? Also, what does `In the USERTYPE schema you should send back an array of user ids.` mean?

Comment: @Eni and UzielValdez I figure it out! Both of your comments, around the same time, helped me. Sorry Eni, but I selected Uziel's answer as it included what I needed to do more explicitly, but huge thanks to both of you.

Comment: @popctrl Glad it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphQL APIs are organized in terms of types and fields, I recommend creating separate queries for User types and Club types, if someone is querying only userIds they will use the user query.

query for user:

```
query {
  users {
   id
  }
}
```

query for club:

```
query {
  club {
   clubID
   clubName
   userId
  }
}
```

if someone is trying to querying users/club you can add the club type to the User type like this:

```
query {
  users {
   id
   club {
    clubID
    clubName
   }
  }
}
```

in your user type there will be a field called club which is going to be type club and in the resolver it will call the club query with `obj.userId` as a parameter, the beauty of GraphQL is that you let the client decide what fields to fetch.

you can see an example of nested query [here](https://medium.com/@tkssharma/wrapping-a-rest-api-in-graphql-querying-graphql-779345035949)

EDIT: Then in your case you can modify your userType to include clubs where the user belongs to, you don't need that condition in your `clubQueryField` the condition will be on the query the client is making, so let say your user type is this:

UserType:

```
export default new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'UserType',
  fields: {
    userId: {
      description: 'user id',
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    email: {
      description: 'user email',
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    clubs: {
      description: 'User clubs',
      type: new GraphQLList(ClubType),
      resolve: (obj, args, _) => {
        return getUserClubs(obj.userId);
      }
    },
  }
});
```

then if your client needs only the user it will request something like this:

```
  query {
    User {
     userId
     email
     }
  }
```

and if the client needs user and clubs it will request something like this:

```
query {
    User {
     userId
     email
     clubs {
        field1
        field2
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Wow, that's much easier than expected. So how do implement that? I tried something like `user.ClubIDs = clubQueryField`, but all I get is "Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field User.ClubIDs."

Comment: It's hard to know without looking at your code, but that sounds like a type issue, if you want your field to return an array your type has to be new instance of GraphQLList i.e. `new GraphQLList(club)` and you have to make sure you are resolving an iterable collection, try debugging your response and see what are you returning in your db call, if you can provide some code sample that will be better.

Comment: Check out my edit. It is indeed a list, I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: any particular reason that you need that conditional? please check my edit to the answer

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL has a lazy loading feature that takes care of other fields in the query. If user writes the following query:

```
query{
   users{
    id
   }
}
```

it gets the user ids and it does not looking for other fields obviously. It definitely depends on your resolver though. If you write the resolver something like this: `users { resolve: body => get_user_id}`, it gets the user ids from the database.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm, I think you've misunderstood me - I understand that GraphQL does lazy loading, my question has to do with what DB requests need to be done in the resolve function

Comment: Ah, it depends to your database and the interface you use to connect ot DB and fetch the data. For example, I use rest api, so I fetch the user ids in get_user_id() function using JavaScript and fetch library.